# Connect Playstation Console via VPN to the internet

Tags: 12.04, vpn, ps3

I have a VPN connection to the internet with my PC and want to connect my Playstation 3 to the internet. I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't connect it through your computer. You plug the playstation in to your modem or router.

Comment: The problem is: The only way for me to connect to the internet is via VPN. And as far as I know, I can't use VPN on ps3.